# WebScraping in R: extract names from `href` tags

Tags: r, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(xml2)
url_imb <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature'
web_page<-read_html(url_imb)
```

I want to extract all Directors names related to `adv_li_dr_0`tags.

This is what I did:
CSS SELECTOR:

```
directors_0<-html_text(html_nodes(web_page,"p a"))
```

XPATH SELECTOR:

```
directors_0<-html_attr(html_nodes(web_page,xpath='//p[@class=""]//a'),"href")
```

It is incomplete of course. But can you help me? How to extract elemnts related to a tag in `href`.

Comment: Is this what you're after? `web_page %>%
  html_nodes(".text-muted+ p a:nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text()` ?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns yes it is. Could you provide the XPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a css attribute = value selector with contains operator to specify the href attribute must contain the substring `adv_li_dr_` . Note I have dropped the 0 on the assumption you want all directors. If you want only the first director for each film then put the 0 in on the end. Note this should be faster and less fragile than xpath.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url_imb <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature'
directors <-read_html(url_imb) %>% html_nodes('[href*=adv_li_dr_]')%>%html_text()
```

---

**Reading:**

1. [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(xml2)
url_imb <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature'
directors <- read_html(url_imb) %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//p[contains(text(),'Director')]/a[contains(@href, '_dr')]") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: not yet. As you can see it doesnt return the directors. It returns the tags: `adv_li_dr_0` and `adv_li_st_X`. It returns the actors too. I only want the Directors from `adv_li_dr_0`tag

Comment: This is what I did with your code: `html_text(html_nodes(web_page,xpath = "//p[contains(text(),'Director')]") )`. I just erase the `/a`. And manually separated the Directors names. It should have a clever way to do this directly.

Comment: many thanks! I have to learn how to work with `contains` argument. Please, could you give any reference to understand how to work with `contains`??

Comment: Don't now for specific tutorial, but you can find many questions about  xpath and 'contains' in general.